# Program Exits with Segmentation Fault (SEGV) When Started by a Sytemd Service

Tags: segmentation-fault, systemd-unit

I have coded a program to control a USB camera that is connected to an NVidia Xavier NX. The program runs fine and does what it's supposed to do when I run it manually with the command:

`./<name-of-the-executable> -cfg <path-to-config-file.json>`

The program works whether I start it as a user or root. Then I write a script that automates the process to run the application. It exports an environment variable that points to the USB transport layer file (.ct and .xml), kills the already running application for restarting cleanly, goes to the directory of the executable, and executes the command run the program.

This .sh script also works fine when started as user or root. Now **the problem** arises here:

When I make a unit file for systemd to run the program at boot as a service, I get a SEGV signal and program aborts. The service file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Alvium Camera

[Service]
Type=forking
User=ekin
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c '. /opt/ekinCameraController/alvium/SetGenTLPath.sh'
ExecStart=/opt/ekinCameraController/startAlviumCamera.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The program creates LWPs (light weight processes) during runtime, that is why I set the type as "forking" but I don't know if this is considered as a daemonizing process. Yet, nothing different happens when I change the type as "simple"; the program still stops with SEGV.

I check the coredumpctl by outputting to gdb and the result is this:

`coredumpctl gdb 8968`

```
           PID: 8968 (AlviumCameraCon)
           UID: 1000 (ekin)
           GID: 1000 (ekin)
        Signal: 11 (SEGV)
     Timestamp: Tue 2022-08-09 10:40:45 +03 (21s ago)
  Command Line: ./AlviumCameraController -cfg alviumCamera.json -log 0
    Executable: /opt/ekinCameraController/AlviumCameraController
 Control Group: /system.slice/alviumCamera.service
          Unit: alviumCamera.service
         Slice: system.slice
       Boot ID: 053bf5a1b2864c22ae5b157ec06d20a1
    Machine ID: a3d9197b765643568af09eb2bd3e5ce7
      Hostname: 4-6-rev2-NVMe
.
.
.
[New LWP 8976]
[New LWP 8977]
[New LWP 8974]
[New LWP 8975]
[New LWP 8978]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `./AlviumCameraController -cfg alviumCamera.json -log 0'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x0000007fa9b428a4 in AVT::VmbAPI::Feature::GetValue(long long&) const () from /media/sd/workspace/ekincameracontroller/lib/vimba/6.0/x64/gcc-arm/libVimbaCPP.so
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7f8dff9e10 (LWP 8989))]
```

The backtrace of this process shows:

```
#0  0x0000007fa9b428a4 in ?? ()
#1  0x000000555bafb3b4 in AVT::VmbAPI::Examples::AlviumCam::PrepareCamera (this=0x5576cd80b0) at /media/sd/workspace/ekincameracontroller/src/Camera/Alvium/AlviumCam.cpp:891
#2  0x000000555bafc8a4 in std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> > (__s=0x555bb28e58 "response: ", __out=...) at /usr/include/c++/7/ostream:561
#3  AVT::VmbAPI::Examples::AlviumCam::StartContinuousImageAcquisition (this=0x5576cd80b0, Config=...) at /media/sd/workspace/ekincameracontroller/src/Camera/Alvium/AlviumCam.cpp:531
#4  0x000000555bb01170 in std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> > (__s=0x555bb292c8 " Format:", __out=...) at /usr/include/c++/7/ostream:561
#5  AVT::VmbAPI::Examples::PrintFrameInfo (pFrame=...) at /media/sd/workspace/ekincameracontroller/src/Camera/Alvium/FrameObserver.cpp:151
#6  0x0000007fa921be94 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

What should I get from these? Now I know that GetValue function from libVimbaCPP.so returns a message saying the call is invalid.

`SP_ACCESS(pCamera)->GetFeatureByName(Name, feature);`

And SP_ACCESS is defined as:

`#define SP_ACCESS( sp )         (sp).get()`

But I don't know how to proceed.

To compare the coredumpctl message to the one when the program is executed manually you can see the following gdb output:

```
           PID: 8549 (AlviumCameraCon)
           UID: 1000 (ekin)
           GID: 1000 (ekin)
        Signal: 6 (ABRT)
     Timestamp: Tue 2022-08-09 10:37:35 +03 (58s ago)
  Command Line: ./AlviumCameraController -cfg alviumCamera.json -log 0
    Executable: /opt/ekinCameraController/AlviumCameraController
 Control Group: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-6.scope
          Unit: session-6.scope
         Slice: user-1000.slice
       Session: 6
     Owner UID: 1000 (ekin)
       Boot ID: 053bf5a1b2864c22ae5b157ec06d20a1
    Machine ID: a3d9197b765643568af09eb2bd3e5ce7
      Hostname: 4-6-rev2-NVMe
       Storage: /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.AlviumCameraCon.1000.053bf5a1b2864c22ae5b157ec06d20a1.8549.1660030655000000.lz4
       Message: Process 8549 (AlviumCameraCon) of user 1000 dumped core.
.
.
.
[New LWP 8552]
[New LWP 8553]
[New LWP 8574]
[New LWP 8554]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `./AlviumCameraController -cfg alviumCamera.json -log 0'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
51      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7f7cfe0010 (LWP 8549))]
(gdb) quit
```

Could you help me find out why there is segmentation fault when the program is controlled by system? coredumpctl shows the source of the fault but I cannot figure out how to resolve it. Here are some more details from the journalctl if it helps:

```
...
Ağu 09 10:40:45 4-6-rev2-NVMe startAlviumCamera.sh[8967]: Parameter GainAutoMinis invalid!
Ağu 09 10:40:45 4-6-rev2-NVMe startAlviumCamera.sh[8967]: Parameter GainAutoMaxis invalid!
Ağu 09 10:40:45 4-6-rev2-NVMe startAlviumCamera.sh[8967]: Parameter Gammais invalid!
Ağu 09 10:40:45 4-6-rev2-NVMe startAlviumCamera.sh[8967]: 3 - Preparing camera 5.
Ağu 09 10:40:45 4-6-rev2-NVMe startAlviumCamera.sh[8967]: 3 - Preparing camera 6.
Ağu 09 10:40:46 4-6-rev2-NVMe startAlviumCamera.sh[8967]: /opt/ekinCameraController/startAlviumCamera.sh: line 22:  8968 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./AlviumCameraController -cfg
Ağu 09 10:40:46 4-6-rev2-NVMe systemd[1]: alviumCamera.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=139
Ağu 09 10:40:46 4-6-rev2-NVMe systemd[1]: alviumCamera.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Ağu 09 10:40:46 4-6-rev2-NVMe systemd[1]: Failed to start Alvium Camera.
```

The lines "Parameter X is invalid!" suggests that I cannot reach the camera pointer. I do not know why this happens and how to resolve it. I appreciate any help!

Comment: Awesome! You already have a core dump! Good work. Now, what does gdb tell you when you `backtrace` in that? (You might need to look around in other threads, using `info threads` to list, and `thread N` to switch threads.

Comment: But to be completely honest here: this sounds like you have a bug in your software, and we don't even have that software! If you suspect you're deteferencing a null ptr, you should probably make sure to check the success of however you got that pointer.

Comment: First thing I would do is get rid of the `ExecStartPre` and merge `/opt/ekinCameraController/alvium/SetGenTLPath.sh` & `/opt/ekinCameraController/startAlviumCamera.sh` into a single file. There is zero reason to have it setup like that.

Comment: Thank you Marcus, I am not sure how to get the backtrace of a program but in the coredumpctl output a stack trace is shown. It shows the last function calls before the core dump.  T-I will check with info threads and thread N too. If this is a bug in the software and if I am passing around a null pointer, how does it work when it is not invoked by systemd? This is the key point that confuses me this much.

Comment: Thanks Bib, I had tried it that way before but the result was the same. I have shared the most recent one of my trial-and-error attempts here. I am taking the changes back as you have suggested.